# Regular expression to validate that the entered date is not before 1 jan 2000

Tags: c#, asp.net, regex

I need a regular expression to check that the given date is not before 1 jan 2000, If the user enters the date before 1 jan 2000 it gives error otherwise no work.
I am using a text box for user input with the ajax date time piker.

I want to check it on client side not server side.
Any code, suggestion or help is appreciated.

Comment: What have you tried? What didn't work? Please post your code and explain where you are having difficulties.

Comment: What date format do you use? And, are you sure regular expression is the best way to check such a requirement?

Comment: I want to check it on client side, so I think regular expression is the best way because my page contains a lot of textboxes .

Answer (score 3):

If you are on server side code, why don't you check use something like this:

```
if (dtPicker.Date != null) {
    if ( dtPicker.Date.Year < 2000 ) {
        isValid = false;
    }
}
```

Is there any reason to test with an regular expression?

In general, a regular expression will have problems when you change the localizatino, eg the user enters the date using German or Italian or some other localization.

Comment: I want to check it on a client side not server side.

Comment: @waqar then do the same thing in javascript.

Answer (score 0):

Try `/(\d{1,2}\.){2}2\d{3}/`

First two months (not  checked for validity), then a year starting with 2.

Comment: Depending on how many formats are accepted and which this might or might not work. E.g. in Europe yyyy/mm/dd is common

Comment: Won't work for dates in the 31st century and onwards though may start working again in the 201st century. ;-)